# Android Fragment pass information between fragements of same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to fragments and am having a little trouble wrapping my head around certain concepts. At the moment, I am dealing with two fragments, the first is my user interface for the page, the second is a custom list view. Both fragments will displayed at the same time, on on top of the other. In the first, the user can choose the date, which will then be used in a database call to get the list items for that date.

What I am trying to figure out is first, how to pass the date between the two open fragments and update the second fragment when the date is changed in the first. I hope my question is clear. If not, I can clarify. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about other good options but you can definitely do the following.

Say you have an activity named A and it has contained to fragment b and c. you need to send data from b to c.

As both b and c are both children of activity A, then they can access the method of A. And A can also access  the  child fragments b and c. So to pass info from b to c create a method in A which will pass info to c and call it from b.

To be more specific, and for more information on this topic, you can see the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

So the fragment can access the Activity instance with `getActivity()` and easily call method

```
getActivity().passInfoToC(data);
```

Likewise, your activity can call methods in the fragment by acquiring a reference to the Fragment from FragmentManager, using findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag(). For example:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.setData(data);
```

Then access a method to pass data.

Comment: Ok, so that all makes sense. I would then need a listener in fragment c, correct? Then how do I use that listener to set the date variable for the fragment and reload it?

Comment: why do you need listener? in the setdata you can make the change